# How to show the record in sql with only the last 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql

the original data in table X

```
+----------+-----+
|Date      |Count|
+----------+-----+
|2014-01-15|44   |
+----------+-----+
|2014-01-01|5    |
+----------+-----+
|2013-12-10|1    |
+----------+-----+
```

what I want to display is below :

```
+----------+-----+
|Date      |Count|
+----------+-----+
|2014-01-15|44   |
+----------+-----+
|2014-01-14|0    |
+----------+-----+
|2014-01-13|0    |
+----------+-----+
|2014-01-12|0    |
+----------+-----+
|...       |...  |
```

*p/s and so on until 2013-12-14 or 2013-12-15

*how to solve the problem - 'curdate'/'NOW'/'subdate' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Regardless of RDBMS you can do this using a Numbers table. With most of RBDMS you can use recursive queries

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you have to do some thing like this:

```
select date_sub(date(now()), interval n.n day), coalesce(t.`count`, 0)
from (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      . . .
      select 30
     ) n left join
     table t
     on t.date = date_sub(date(now()), interval n.n day);
```

The first part is a manual list of 30 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a date lookup table and then use an `outer join` with `date_sub`.  This query should work for you:

```
select d.datefield, coalesce(x.count,0) count
from datelookup d
  left join x on d.datefield = x.datefield
where d.datefield > date_sub(curdate(), interval 30 day)
  and d.datefield <= curdate()
order by d.datefield desc
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81e06f/5)

Comment: hi, is it must have a date lookup table in order to display it ?

Comment: there is an error - 'curdate' is not a recognized built-in function name.